# Bradley-Terry model to determine the result of a game

Tags: probability

In order to decide the result of a game, I was looking for a probability model and found the following article on wikipedia about the Bradley-Terry model:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bradley%E2%80%93Terry_model

So, let's say I have a team $A$ and a team $B$ with rating $a_1$ and $b_1$. Then by the Bradley Terry model the probability that A will win is equal to:

$P(A > B) = \frac{a_1}{a_1 +b_1}$.

Unfortunately, the wikipedia-article doesn't have a solution for calculating the probability for a tie. Is there any other probability model which considers that also?

Comment: First thing first: do you really want the probability of a tie ? For instance the ELO rating system can take ties into account even though the probabilities are computed as in the Bradley Terry model.

Comment: Second: a (probably very naive) possibility is to go to the second order. In this case, 
$$ P(A > B) = \frac{a_1^2}{(a_1 + b_1)^2}, $$
the symmetric thing for $P(B > A)$ and the probability of a tie is $\frac{2 a_1 b_1}{(a_1 + b_1)^2}$.

Comment: I'm trying to code a football manager game, where a tie in a game should be considered too. But I'll try to understand the ELO rating system - thanks :).

Comment: The ELO rating is used for the FIFA ratings, so this should be appropriate for your purpose.